# What is weak interaction? I need easy and short answer

Tags: radiation, weak-interaction

What is [weak interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction)? I need easy and short answer.

I can't understand the definition of weak force.

Why is it so difficult? Bosons, Mesons, Fermions, parity etc.

Why the fundamental force is too hard to understand?

(I give time for typing this. But it's hard to integrate those forces.)

Gravitational : Force between masses.

Electromagnetic : Force between charges.

Strong interactions : Strong force in nucleus which locks nuclei from Electromagnetic force.

Those are intuitively understandable.

But weak interaction? What is it?

Comment: Is it essential to understand some particle physics definitions?

Comment: It's *not* too hard to understand but a "short, easy answer" will not give you any sort of understanding of it.  But, perhaps this will help:  http://kidsresearchexpress-2.blogspot.com/2008/09/weak-force.html

Comment: The weak force is a very weak force between left-handed particles, that can also transform them (electron to neutrino, or vice versa; one quark to another type of quark).

Comment: Can the close-voters explain what is *unclear* about this question? It looks to me that OP has a plain-to-see question that's written *three times* in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Gravitation is a weak force but long-range. We observe it while exploring stellar movement and cosmos.

Electromagnetism is a moderate force and long-range. We observe it while normal electromagnetic and electronic experiments.

Strong interaction is short-range but strong. So, we observe it in nuclear physics.

Weak interaction is both very weak and short-range. This is why we don't observe it and hardly imagine it's role.

Weak interaction is an "echo" of electromagnetic interaction, so it also acts on electric charge, but plays role in rare phenomena like beta-decay.

Answer (score 0):

Weak interaction is the interaction that permits Beta decay (a Neutron changes in a proton, an electron and an anti-neutrino).
The gauge bosons that permit this interaction are the W+,W- and the Z boson. They have big masses of 80 GeV and 91 GeV and that is why the Weak interaction has such a small range. During Beta Decay a down quark transforms into an up quark and emits a W- boson and due to it's big mass it transforms into an electron and an anti-neutrino. I hope this is not too complicated. I hope this helped you.